# Can I use s3 as a Hive storage outside the Amazon EMR environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive, emr

I have case where I manage the service in a EC2 machine. This machine running Hive and I am planning to use s3 as my hive storage (instead of hdfs). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a detailed write up of how to do this here http://blog.mustardgrain.com/2010/09/30/using-hive-with-existing-files-on-s3/

Some choice bits:

> Now, let’s change our configuration a bit so that we can access the S3
>   bucket with all our data. First, we need to include the following
>   configuration. This can be done via HIVE_OPTS, configuration files
>   ($HIVE_HOME/conf/hive-site.xml), or via Hive CLI’s SET command.
>
> Here are the configuration parameters:
>
> **Name** fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId    **Value** Your S3 access key
>
> **Name** fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey **Value** Your S3 secret access key

And:

> Whether you prefer the term veneer, façade, wrapper, or whatever, we need to 
>   tell Hive where to find our data and the format of the files. Let’s
>   create a Hive table definition that references the data in S3:
>
> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE mydata (key STRING, value INT)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '='
> LOCATION 's3n://mys3bucket/';
> ```

Comment: does it utilize EMRFS? Because I read this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html, it said that if using EMRFS, then it supports read-after-write-consistency, which is s3 only provides eventual-consistency.

Comment: If you are running a version of Hadoop that isn't EMR on an EC2 instance, then I think it won't be using EMRFS with read-after-write-consistency, but anyway that's a different question :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to update the profile on ec2 instance with AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY so that the node on which instance is running can access your s3 bucket.